# Installed 3rd Party Package is Not Loading While Re-Launching Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I am using Delphi5 and Windowss8.

I have installed 3rd party component called MDIWallPaper.

After launching Delphi5 if I try to look for this component I couldn't see, and if I go to Project Menu->Options->Package, this component is unchecked.

If I select that component then it appears as new component palette called 3rd Party, even after saving the settings with selecting the Default check box in the Project Menu->Options, if I close the application and relaunch I still couldn't see the component in the component palette and  if I go to Project Menu->Options->Package, this component is unchecked.

I tried removing and reinstalling this component but still same issue.

Any suggestions ?

With Best Regards.

Vishal

Comment: Did you launch Delphi as administrator? Sometimes IDE doesn't have permission to change its own files (from system folder C:\program files\borland ...), that's why all the preferences are lost after closing program. Also, I had similar problems with my own component, turned out, it loaded some files in initialization section and default directory was different at startup and after IDE is loaded, so when I installed component, it worked but couldn't load when delphi is started again. After exception in initialization (bad thing, no information) delphi just refused to load this component.

Comment: Your question is tagged Delphi 7 but your question is talking about Delphi 5...

Comment: Probably environmental. You installed delphi to program files folder and virtualization is confuzzling you.

Comment: @David : Installing Delphi 5 to other folder location other than Program Files worked perfectly. Thanks a lot David.You Just ROCKSSSS !!!!!